# Unable to debug Azure function in VS 2019

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, visual-studio-2019

I am having a lot of trouble debugging a .NET Core 2.2 Azure function in VS 2019 that uses version 1.0.29 of the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions package. When I try to debug I get the following, how can I fix this?

[image: Invalid Output Type Error]

Note: I am not able to upgrade framework or package versions.

Edit: A colleague can debug a copy of the same Azure function on their PC without issue.

Thanks

Comment: You cant debug a project that's of output type, Class Library. You need to add a console project to your solution and use that to test the methods you want to test from your class library project

Comment: @Jawad please see the edit above

Comment: Do you have more than one project in your solution? Change the startup project to the one that your colleague is running. [see here for setting startup project](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/VSStartupProjects.aspx#:~:text=To%20change%20the%20startup%20project,press%20F5%20to%20start%20it.)

Comment: @Jawad already did.

Comment: Can you go to this: `...\Functionappname\bin\Debug\netcoreappx.x`? I want to see the structure.

Comment: @BowmanZhu can't due to being a client solution.

Comment: @radulfr What? I dont understand what you mean.

Comment: Just suggest, from your describe, your code can be run from your colleague's PC. So the problem maybe comes from the installed tools of azure. You can go to the VS installer and try to reinstall the azure tools components. Then try to turn on the VS and create a new function app. That may solve the problem.

Comment: Or try to restart your VS, this should not be the problem with the code. Any update please let us know.:)

Comment: @BowmanZhu I have since reinstalled VS 2019 in an attempt to fix it. This did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end what fixed it was wiping away my copy of the repo and repulling it. Something seems to have become corrupted in my local version.